# How to get the most exact clock in linux user space application?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, clock

I have an embedded system and I would like to share in a kernel module/driver the most accurate clock with an userspace application which is very sensitive to the clock, and should be the most accurate.

1. These [functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) requires context switch and a huge overhead and the clock won't be accurate since the syscall.
2. I thought to increase a shared integer every [jiffy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_%28time%29) from the kernel module, assuming the userspace application can access it directly, the problem is that I can't share an `integer/long` which is not aligned to a page size and declare a whole new page for only one `long` variable is a huge overhead.

What should I do?

Comment: You are asking for "accuracy" yet your requirements sound to me more like latency bounds.  Are you trying to eliminate jitter due to computing overhead or return a time properly synchronized to an external source?  Also note that generally the jiffies counter is **not** the most precise timer available to the hardware.

Comment: @AndyRoss 
I would like the userspace to see the clock the kernel space sees, if it were in veri-log or any other RTL I would like them to have the same clk. however what is the most precise counter?

Comment: The kernel already provides a system call to get the time.  See scai's answer.  In general it's as fast as it can be practically made to be.  What's wrong with it?  I think you need to spell your requirements out a lot clearer than you are.

Comment: Depending in your SoC you might be able to mmap an internal clockcycle counter into your userspace, by mmaping /dev/mem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `clock_gettime()` for obtaining the current time (since startup) with either `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (monotonic but *not* steady as it is influenced by NTP) or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` (monotonic and steady, but Linux specific and requires a kernel >= 2.6.28).

For waking up at exact intervals, use `clock_nanosleep()` and specify `TIMER_ABSTIME`. Unfortunately `clock_nanosleep()` only supports `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and not `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`, so you cannot pass a wakeup time obtained with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` because these clocks may differ. Don't forget to check the return code for `EINTR`.

Comment: The kernel side of `clock_gettime()` is surprisingly heavy - on OMAP4 at least - and possibly on for other SoCs as well.

As others have suggested, getting access to the CPU's time-base register might well be a good idea if you need to call it frequently.

Comment: @Marko thanks but How can I get an access to the time-base register?

Comment: @0x90 consult your SoC datasheet.  Whatever you do is unlikely to be very portable.

Comment: I'm curious, why `clock_nanosleep()` does not yet support CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW. Even now, in 2016 on Debian Jessie it returns EOPNOTSUPP.